# How to remove this character only if it is not followed by 'u'?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this little method in some JavaScript classes that communicates with server through php, using JSON:

```
formUpload.prototype.cleanResult = function(dirtResult){
    var res = dirtResult.slice(dirtResult.indexOf("{"), dirtResult.lastIndexOf("}")+1);
    res = res.replace(/\\/g, "");
    return res;
}
```

First, I get only the JSON (sometimes there is warnings in text result). Than I unescape (remove backslashes) because sometimes the JSON is complex and some backslash generate errors when parsing in JavaScript. I try to get rid with those backslashes, but I'm not sure if it is even possible. Meanwhile, the Regular Expression remove when receiving the response.

The problem is when there is a special character, it is encoded in utf-8 (\uXXXX), and if this backslash is removed, the character will not be recognized, the result will be uXXXX in the text.

So I need a regular expression that removes the backslashes when there isn't a "u" after, gut that's beyond my knowledge so far...

Also, a good tutorial will be cool!

EDIT: here is a simple response:

```
{"erro":"dir","msg":"N\u00e3o existe o diret\u00f3rio e n\u00e3o foi poss\u00edvel cri\u00e1-lo.","descr":"dir:/Library/WebServer/Documents/www/sintran/fotos"}
```

I don't have an example when undesired backslashes appears, but is related to single quotes, multidimensional arrays, etc..

Comment: Why are you trying to "post-process" a JSON string?  What does the *original* JSON look like?  What problems are you having with it?  Trying to remove the slashes is probably not the solution to your problem.

Comment: if you are getting real JSON, there would be no JS paring errors handling the data. where does the JSON come from? It sounds like someone is hand-building JSON server-side instead of using a JSON server-side library or feature, like PHP's json_encode(). It's easy to make such hand-built output "pretty much work", but hard to make it work robustly in edge cases like you describe.

Comment: I'm trying to make a "bulletproof" code, and this cleaning (post-process) is working fine, I just have to prevent from mess with utf-8 special characters. I know is a pragmatic way (where this JSON came from???) but sometimes life is cruel...

Comment: @GustavoPinent: For bulletproof code just use ensure that the JSON is valid. Then you will be able to feed it into [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) which does not have any problems with correct backslashes.

Comment: This is not a bulletproff code, just a code that works where there is no bullets at all. I can't guarantee there will be no wrong backslashes, I need to clean the text, can you help me?

Comment: @GustavoPinent: So, you are getting invalid JSON and you are trying to fix it?

Comment: Yes. I know is not the best solution, but at list the system will keep working. I'll keep a silent error catch (console.log) so I can see a irregular JSON coming in and can manage the problem. But the system needs to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a negative lookahead. From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> Negative lookahead is indispensable if you want to match something not
>   followed by something else.

#### Sample code

```
formUpload.prototype.cleanResult = function(dirtResult){
    return dirtResult.replace(/\\(?!u)/g, '');
}
```

#### Regular expression

```
\\(?!u)
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/qR2hA0

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I noticed that unicode can also have the mark "\x". I'll investigate. In this case, I'll have to lookahead for !u or !x. Will be my homework!